# I have 3 Windows8 PCs and use the same MS login on each and all share desktop settings, how do I stop this?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have 3 different computers now all running Windows 8 (desktop, laptop and tablet - purchased in different countries it should be noted).  I use the same internet enabled MS user account to login on all the computers.

I've just recently realised that Windows is trying to be clever and share my environment settings across all the systems.  However due to their huge differences in screen resolutions and other hardware such as keyboard layouts the last thing I want is for my font size settings to be identical on all 3 systems.  Worse, the keyboard layout is even being shared across all the systems so suddenly on my laptop all the shift functions of the numbers were doing something unexpected.

This seems really ridiculous that windows would just unquestionably copy these settings over despite previously knowing that the keyboards were from different countries.   Anyhow, that's another thing to raise with MS I guess.

So how do I stop this automatic sharing of all the environment settings?

Comment: I think you need to make 2 more microsoft IDs.

Comment: Is that really the only way though?

Comment: You can always change the account to a local account, but you lose access to Skydrive (OneDrive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily adjust which settings sync, or turn Sync off altogether. Open the Charms bar (swipe from the right, or move your mouse to the bottom right corner), click 'Settings', click 'Change PC Settings', then click on 'OneDrive'. You will now see the 'Sync Settings' option on the left menu. There are sliders to turn on or off which settings will sync. In your case, the Language settings option under the 'Other Settings' category is what you want to turn off. 
This is also explained [in this article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/sync-settings-pcs).

Hope this helps,

Comment: Brilliant @WinOutreach4  just what I needed!